# Unable to get Vodaphone GPRS settings for Samsung Galaxy Young GT-S6312

Tags: samsung

I am using Samsung Galaxy Young GT-S6312. I am unable to download anything through Vodaphone internet (error message displays). Whenever I am trying to get Vodaphone internet settings, I get the reply "Your handset will not compatible to get the setting". So, I download the Vodaphone live setting, but downloading is not possible, whether I am browsing all internet sites.  I am already done anything such as restore factory data, mobile restart etc.

I am also trying with Aircel & Airtel SIM, & I am got the positive service (do anything) through these service provider such as browsing, downloading & online playing.

Comment: Have you tried entering the APN settings manually? Which Android version are you running? Which country do you live in?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a text message "VL" to 52586. If you get the same error message as a reply, you'll have to call the customer care and they'll guide you to set up gprs on your phone manually. 
This happened to a friend of mine and he fixed it by calling the CC.